# Increasing a value each time a function passes through a for loop

Tags: python, json, for-loop, key, increment

I am trying to make a for loop that returns response.json[i] from an API, with i increasing by 1 each time through the loop.

Example:

```
import requests
import json 

def get_url():
    url = "https://bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com/news/search"    

    querystring = {"q":"bitcoin","count":"20","textFormat":"Raw","safeSearch":"Off"}        

    headers = {
        'x-bingapis-sdk': "true",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "api_key"
        }       

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)    
    print(response.json()["value"][i]["url"]) # Here is where I need i to increase each time
for i in range(10):
    get_url()
```

My goal is for get_url() to run 10 times, each time printing the response associated with the increasing i value. Sorry if this is worded poorly, I am a total beginner and 100% self taught. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can pass `i` as a paremeter. `def get_url(i):` and then `for i in range(10): get_url(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `i` as an argument to `get_url`:

```
def get_url(i):
```

and then add it to your `get_url` call in your `for` loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    get_url(i)
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what I needed. I upvoted your answer but I don't have enough rep for it to be counted apparently. This definitely answers my question and is very clear!

Comment: You should be able to "accept" the answer even without rep.  :)

Comment: found it! Now if I also have another similar function also calling to an API, where I use the output of get_url(i) for the querystring, how would I pass the I argument to the next/main function? For example, if my main function is scrape_url() and uses the url from get_url(), how would I write the for loop so scrape_url() loops using the next url from the increasing i value of get_url() from the original loop?

Comment: It's the exact same deal.  Add the argument in the `def` line so that you can use it in the body of the function, and then pass it when you call the function.  (It doesn't need to have the same name in both places; the `def` line defines what it's called within the body of the function, but when you call the function the value can be named however you want.)

Comment: For example: `def scrape_url(url)` to define the function as taking a parameter that will be called `url` in the body of the function, and then `scrape_url(get_url(i))` to call it on the `i`th URL.  Note that you will want to change your `get_url` function to `return` the URL rather than `print`ing it!